# using grep to find the value of a string

Tags: grep

I have file(file.txt) contains the following

```
aa=testing
bb=hello
cc=hi
```

Expected result

the value of aa is testing

How to use grep to find the value of aa?

Comment: `grep aa= file.txt`, but if you want the output to literally be `the value of aa is testing` , you can't use grep.

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive lookbehind in grep:

```
grep -Po "(?<=aa=).*" file.txt
```

*Output*

```
testing
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oP 'aa=\K.*' file.txt
```

Output:

```
testing
```

See: http://www.charlestonsw.com/perl-regular-expression-k-trick/

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F= '/^aa=/ { print $2 }' file
sed -n '/^aa=/s|^.*=||p' file
sed -n 's|^aa=||p' file
```

Output:

```
testing
```

Comment: Some golfing on the `awk` and you get `awk -F= '/^aa/ && $0=$2'`